# Theoretical JavaScript events runtime

Tags: javascript

I have a theoretical core JavaScript question. Is it guaranteed that the following example will give the following result in every case?

```
Test fired
Done
```

---

```js
var body = $('body')
  .on('test', function() {
    console.log('Test fired');
  });

body.trigger('test');
console.log('Done');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, as long as nothing is asynchronous, the event will always fire before moving on to the next line.

Comment: Yes, so long as jQuery doesn't change it's API

Comment: Yes, unless browser crashes meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `. trigger()` is a synchonous operation, just like `console. log()`.

Since JavaScript is single-threaded the order of execution in your example is guaranteed.

Comment: Not only `trigger` is synchronous - native DOM `.dispatchEvent` too.